# Не записываются в данные в excel таблицу с помощью pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Не записываются данные в excel таблицу, записывается только последняя строка. Пробовал в разных положениях результат тот же. Если кто знает подскажите где ошибка?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

while True:
    print('Выберите категорию товара: легковые шины, грузовые шины, внедорожные шины')
    name = input()
    if name == 'легковые шины':
        get_name = 'https://samara.express-shina.ru/search/legkovyie-shinyi'
    elif name == 'грузовые шины':
        get_name = 'https://samara.express-shina.ru/search/gruzovyie-shinyi'
    elif name == 'внедорожные шины':
        get_name = 'https://samara.express-shina.ru/search/vnedorozhnyie-shinyi'
    else:
        print('Такой категории нет')

    print('Введите название файла латинскими буквами')
    file_name = str(input())

    count = 1
    while count <= 3:
        url = f'{get_name}?num={count}'
        data = requests.get(url).text
        block = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
        heads = block.find_all('div', class_='b-offer__boxes')
        for i in heads:
            get_url = i.find_next('a').get('href')
            # print('https://samara.express-shina.ru'+get_url)
            w = ('https://samara.express-shina.ru' + get_url)
            seac = requests.get(w).text
            look = BeautifulSoup(seac, 'lxml')
            leen = look.find('div', class_='header_product_page').find('h1')
            print(leen.text.strip())
            nazvan = (leen.text.strip())
            price = look.find('span', class_='price_new')
            print(price.text.strip())
            cena = (price.text.strip())
            articul = look.find('span', class_='articul')
            print(articul.text.strip())
            codde = (articul.text.strip())
            img = look.find('div', class_='inner_images').find('img').get('src')
            print('https://samara.express-shina.ru' + img)
            pixx = ('https://samara.express-shina.ru' + img)
            print('\n')

            storage = {'zagol': nazvan,
                       'cena': cena,
                       'articul': codde,
                       'img': pixx}

            df = pd.DataFrame({
                'NAME': [storage['zagol']],
                'PRICE': [storage['cena']],
                'ARTICUL': [storage['articul']],
                'IMG': [storage['img']]
            })
            df.to_excel(f'{file_name}.xlsx')

        count += 1
```

Comment: На каждой итерации цикла `while count <= 3` вы создаете новый фрейм и записываете его в файл Excel с одинаковым именем. Предыдущий файл затирается новым, и по завершении цикла у вас файл Excel, содержащий последний фрейм (строку).

Comment: Убрал итерацию вообще т.е. данные собираются с одной страницы, результат тот же самый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Накапливайте данные в список. И уже после всей обработки делайте датафрейм и записывайте его в файл за один раз:

```py
    lst = []
    while count <= 3:
            ...
            # df = pd.DataFrame({
            lst.append({
                'NAME': [storage['zagol']],
                'PRICE': [storage['cena']],
                'ARTICUL': [storage['articul']],
                'IMG': [storage['img']]
            })

        count += 1

    # все циклы закончились, сохраняем в эксель
    df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
    df.to_excel(f'{file_name}.xlsx')
```

Comment: Отлично! Всё работает, благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

как я понимаю Алексей тебе правильно подсказал.

я бы (вкратце) делал примерно так:

1. создаем пустой df1
2. в цикле парсинга создаем df2 с одной строкой (такая же структура как df1)
3. через pd.concat объединяем  `df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index = True)`
4. вне цикла записываем df1

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-one-row-in-an-existing-pandas-dataframe/

PS. вроде как append признан устаревшим и не поддерживается.

Comment: Так то всё правильно, но постоянно делать `concat` - очень неэффективно.

Comment: да, мой вариант очень неэффективен по скорости, через накопление в словаре как у CrazyElf
 будет на несколько порядков быстрее.

Comment: Да ладно уж на несколько. Хорошо если на порядок. Хотя будет зависеть от размера финального датафрейма